# How to make a LINQ Statement on many-to-many tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I Have 2 tables : (Book,Tags)the relation between them is many to many .

The **Book** Table Contain id,name,edition....

The **Tags** Table Contain Id,Name .

Since the relation many to many the EF Created automatically another table named :

**TagBooks** it's hold the id of both tables .

and I want to get all the books where the tag id = 80 from TagBooks Table but I have no idea how to do that ..

and I tried this , but I got only one result since I did not do it right :

```
var result = db.Books.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(s => s.Id == id)).ToList();
```

Comment: That's the right query.

Comment: Uhm ... are you sure (assuming you don't just have one book with that tag) you are reusing tags? If you list all Tags, are there any duplicates? If you list Tag.Books, is there more than one?

Comment: It's return only 1 item , while actually for example the tag id =80 should return 15 items ..

Comment: Add a log, and post the SQL that it executed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: So in TagBooks there are 15 entries with references to the Tag with id 80.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It's solved , thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easier to find the tag first and then get the books for that tag

```
var result =
    db.Tags
      .Where(t => t.Id == id)
      .SelectMany(t => t.Books)
      .ToList();
```

Although I'm not sure why your original attempt does not work for you

Comment: It's same as mine , but I don't know why your code works fine , Any way thanks